# configuring grails root UrlMappings

Tags: grails

Let's say I have a bunch of gsp files in my view root. e.g.

version.gsp: (should be rendered as /version )

```
${grailsApplication.metadata.getProperty('info.app.version')}
```

build.gsp: (should be rendered as /build )

```
${grailsApplication.metadata.getProperty('info.app.build.date')}
```

Is there a way I can configure them in UrlMappings.groovy in one go? I realise I can do

```
        "/version"(view: '/version')
        "/build"(view: '/build')
```

but is there a way to do it generically for all views in the root?